# Error read_html R

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping

I am running the following code in R:

```
library(XML)
library(xml2)    
doc <- read_html(paste0("http://www.fincaraiz.com.co/arriendos/bogota/"))
```

But I have reiceved the following error message:

```
Error: Failed to parse text
```

Why have I received this error? days before the code was working normally

Comment: did the website have change in between ? Would make sens...

Comment: For some reason it's having a problem opening a `url` connection, so do it manually, e.g. `read_html(url("http://www.fincaraiz.com.co/arriendos/bogota/"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to installing the **rvest** package:

```
install.packages('rvest')

library('rvest')

doc <- read_html(paste0("http://www.fincaraiz.com.co/arriendos/bogota/"))
```